# Generating  Powerpoint PPT with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, powerpoint

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate powerpoint ppts within ColdFusion? I can't rely on the approach of installing a copy of office and generate one through COM and I can't use ooxml since my client is still in the office 2003 era. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using Apache POI, specifically their Powerpoint support. Looks to be still in beta though:

http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html

I've used POI to extra from Word docs before and it was rather easy in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 3):

ColdFusion doesn't have built in PPT creation, but you may be able to make something work with OpenOffice.

Look into CFPresentation (CF8), it allows you to create web-based presentations - not actually PPT format, but displayed in the same way via Flash player.

Have you considered using PDF instead? For all intents and purposes except perhaps some animation, PDFs do well replacing PPTs. And CF has tons of PDF creation and manipulation features!

Comment: Unfortunately the presentation must be in PP format, as my client's clients also rely on the components in the PP file to compile their own presentations. So only Powerpoint will do, but thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a good answer, but ColdFusion 9 can turn a cfpresentation into a PowerPoint file, and creating a cfpresentation is pretty damned trivial...

However, this of course requires a server that's still in beta, and a large cash outlay once it's released if you're running your own server.

Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the heads up. And now that CF9 has shipped, I can now build a prototype to show my client; hopefully they'll buy into the upgrade.

Lawrence