# Exporting to Powerpoint from Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, export, powerpoint, cfchart

I was interested in being able to export data from Coldfusion to Powerpoint. I saw this section on StackOverflow 
[Generating  Powerpoint PPT with ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398235/generating-powerpoint-ppt-with-coldfusion)
which was posted almost 3 years ago. I was hoping there would be something more relevent since then instead of using the Apache POI.

I have tried using the cfcontent tag similar to how you would export to excel, I am able to get ppt to open, but a blank template opens up when I use cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint". Ultimately, I will be using this to try to export charts to a ppt slide. I believe cfcharts with the jpg option is the best solution, although I am currently using FusionCharts on my site itself.

Sorry I'm such a noob, but any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into the `<cfpresentation />` family of tags?  It does exactly what you are looking for, allows you to generate PowerPoint files on the server. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7910.html

Comment: That seems to be something that I could use. I see that the <cfpresentation> tag has an attribute of format=ppt. One thing I haven't figured out yet is getting the ppt file to save to my computer from the directory attribute? It seems it saves it locally (which would be the server), so How do I get it?

Comment: once it is generated at the server, you can download it to your own computer either through a link or served from CF using `<cfcontent>`

Comment: Thank you guys, sry i'm such a noob :P

Comment: @Chris M if it was helpful you should mark the answer as correct

Comment: Accepting an answer helps the next person viewing this issue.  Click the check mark to do this.